# C# interfaces method{get;} mean?

Tags: c#

i'm a beginner in OOP, i have problem with an interfaces method that has "get" parameters within, like the code below

```
Vector2 terrain {get;}
```

what "get" mean?? is the method will return the value from get??
thanks

Comment: That is not a method. That is a property. Also try to use google or some other search before asking a basic question like this.

Comment: sorry, i searched it before, and not too understand, that's why i made question here, by the way thanks for the solution, and i got the answer that helped me to understand. that is a read only property which the "get" will executed when the property is read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's "shorthand" syntax for a "getter". Google OO getter and setter for what those are. There is better explainations for getters/setters that I can write here.

For example: http://www.dotnetperls.com/property

Comment: True but for question/answer quality, If I may say, I'd still try to at least include a link to an instance of this documentation to cut one step out of the equation. Very true non-the-less.:)

Answer (score 1):

It's not parameter, This is a property.
Please refer 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The accessor of an interface property does not have a body. Thus, the purpose of the accessors is to indicate whether the property is read-write, read-only, or write-only.

```
Vector2 terrain {get;}
```

this property only have read permission!